# How to include UPI Deeplink URL in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, qr-code

how to make upi payment QR code using google sheet

i want to make a QR code like

upi://pay?pa=1234567890000@sbin1234567.ifsc.npci&pn=Name&am=100&tn=Testing&cu=INR

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=IMAGE("https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl="&ENCODEURL(B10))
```

[image]